# Why is the Azure Blob MD5 Checksum not generated automatically using Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-account

In Logic Apps I've retrieved a CSV file from SharePoint using "Get file content" and used the "Create block Blob V2", but no MD5-Content is created. When I update the Blob manually the MD5 does get created.
Any idea's why the MD5 is not generated when retrieving a file from SharePoint and uploading it to the Blob?

Create Block Blob (V2) Blob content:

```
{
  "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
  "$content": "QTtCO0M7RDtFDQoxOzI7Mzs0OzU="
}
```

Create Block Blob (V2) Output:

```
{
  "Id": "JTJmdGVzdGNvbnRhaW5lciUyZnRlc3RmaWxlMi5jc3Y=",
  "Name": "testfile2.csv",
  "DisplayName": "testfile2.csv",
  "Path": "/testcontainer/testfile2.csv",
  "LastModified": "2021-07-20T18:45:06Z",
  "Size": 20,
  "MediaType": "text/csv",
  "IsFolder": false,
  "ETag": "\"0x8D94BAE7E056750\"",
  "FileLocator": "JTJmdGVzdGNvbnRhaW5lciUyZnRlc3RmaWxlMi5jc3Y=",
  "LastModifiedBy": null
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried reproducing the same using the logic app with the same connectors as per your question and could see CONTENT-MD5 as null. I have used compose with base64 action taking **Create file Content** output to **Create Block Blob(V2)**. 

Here is the Flow of my Logic App
 ```Create file Content-> Compose(output of Create file Content)-> Create Block Blob(V2)``` 

By doing this I could able to generate the CONTENT-MD5 value.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me, I've added ***base64*** Dynamic Expression using **compose** between **Create file Content** and **Create Block blob (V2)** steps doing this I could able to generate `Content-MD5` header value for the blob.

Here is the screenshot of my Logic App.
[image]

and here is the result
[image]